# Python library for parsing code of any language into an AST?

Tags: javascript, python, parsing, libraries, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm looking for a Python library for parsing code into its abstract syntax tree representation. There exists a built-in module, named `ast`, however, it is only designed for parsing Python code, to my understanding. I'm wondering if there is a similar Python library that suits the same purpose, but works with other programming languages. In particular, I'm looking for one that can parse JavaScript code.

If one does not exist, any direction on how I could get started designing my own?

Comment: What languages are you trying to parse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, when you need to parse code written in a language, it’s almost always better to use that language instead.

For parsing JavaScript from Python, you may want to check out [this](https://github.com/Kronuz/esprima-python) module, which can be installed using pip and should work well enough.

Answer (score 4):

The library [tree-sitter](https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/) has a [python binding](https://github.com/tree-sitter/py-tree-sitter), tons of language parsers!